# Can't open the openclinica

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I tried to install the OpenClinica following the instruction (https://github.com/OpenClinica/OpenClinica/wiki/Install-OpenClinica-v3.6-and-higher-on-Windows)

My AWS server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

But I can't start the openclinica page with http://localhost:8080/OpenClinica

In the log, it prompt

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\OC\tomcat\webapps\OpenClinica\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 24, 2016 3:19:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://code.google.com/p/jmesa is already defined
Oct 24, 2016 3:19:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Anyone know how to fix?

Thanks!

Greatvia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OC should have used the Java EE Servlet API via Maven dependency scope `provided` to not include it in the `war` file. To get the `jar` file out of the way, I just moved the file one directory level up.